# Line intersection without endpoints

Tags: geometry, line-intersection

I need to determine whether two lines intersect, but these lines have only starting points. (So that's why this is different from similar questions asked about line intersection). 
The lines are defined as y = dx + a, with d being the gradient. Both lines start in different starting points (x,y).

Comment: just find the point where line 1 y equates line 2 y
say line 1: y = d1*x+a1 and line 2: y = d2x + a2. You just need to find x for when y in both lines are equal: d1x + a1 = d2x + a2 and then solve for x.

Comment: ah very simple, thanks @AymarFisherman!

Comment: @AymarFisherman: I suggest you turn that comment into an answer, since you answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just find the point where line 1 y equates line 2 y say line 1: y = d1*x+a1 and line 2: y = d2x + a2. You just need to find x for when y in both lines are equal: d1x + a1 = d2x + a2 and then solve for x.